# Emanate from a place, not a source

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage, context

Just a nuance question here:

The word "emanate", I know for sure it can be used in reference to a specific source, e.g. "a strange glow emanated from the lamp".

But can it also be used in reference to a place? e.g. "a strange glow was emanating from the middle of my dark apartment" - *the middle* of the dark apartment being the spot or location from which the glow is coming from, not its actual source (which can be, for example, an unperceived ghost).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, a place, a source, a person, a planet, the universe, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emanate) lists the example sentence *Good smells emanated from the **kitchen**.*
Also, one of their recently scraped examples included, *The glow from this particular milky sea spanned 38,000 square miles and appeared to the crew members to emanate from about **32 feet below the surface**, reports The Guardian.*, which uses a relative location like in your question.